# Ignore commas in a text input field when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

So I've made this search that does what its supposed to do front-end wise. However, when submitting  I'd like the query to ignore commas.

Right now I'm using commas to make a comma separated search. The whole thing is, when I submit; the comma's are included and thus messes up my search values.

Is there any way to ignore comma's upon submit?

Example: Searching `[Example][Test]` will actually return `Example,Test`.

I've made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YEr6m/27/)

Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a backend problem, not a frontend problem. What language is your backend in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firster = true;
//capture form submit
$('form.nice').submit(function(e){
    if(firster){
         // if its the first submit prevent default
         e.preventDefault();
         // update input value to have no commas
         var val = $('input').val();
         val = val.replace(/,/g, ' ');
         $('input').val(val);
         // let submit go through and submit
         firster = false;
         $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aDVnT/)**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your profile, I'm guessing you're using python as a server-side language. The issue you're trying to solve is best dealt with server-side: *never* rely on front-end code to escape or format data that is being used in a query... [check Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) for more info

Anyhow, in python, you could try this:

```
ajaxString.replace(",","\", \"")
```

Thiis will replace all commas witIh `" OR "`, so a string like `some, keywords` is translated into `some", "keywords`, just add `some_field IN ("` and the closing `")` to form a valid query. 
Alternatively, you can split the keywords, and deal with them separately (which could come in handy when sorting the results depending on how relevant the results *might* be.

```
searchTerms = ajaxString.split(",")
>>>['some','keywords']
```

That should help you on your way, I hope.

Lastly, I'd suggest just not bothering with developing your own search function at all. Just add a google search to your site, they're the experts. There is just no way you, by yourself, can do better. Or even if you could, just imagine how long it'd take you!
Yes, sometimes a company will create their own search-engine, but only if they have a good reason to do so, and have the resources such an endevour requires. Programming is often all about being *"cleverly lazy"*: Don't reinvent the wheel.